# Show the code (i.e "&entity_name;"), not the corresponding character

Tags: html, html-entities

If I write `&nbsp;` in a HTML file the browser automatically translates it to its corresponding character, in this case a space.

How can I escape from this phase? I mean, if I would like to print just the code (i.e. `&nbsp;`) how can I prevent the browser from doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't stop the browser from treating HTML as HTML.

If you want to include a `&` as data instead of as the start of a character reference, then use the character reference for it:

```
&amp;nbsp;
```

Answer (score -2):

For this you will need JQuery.

Try `.text()` method. http://api.jquery.com/text/

Get the `body` content an then replace it with text.

Means: `$('body').text($('body').html());`.

This will give you an output of your html in plain Text. Actually you can do this with other Elements as well. Replace the Word `body` with the element, class or id you need.